# AngularJS code not working on chrome on localhost in a folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, ubuntu, localhost

I am running simple hello world program (using AngularJS 1.6) from localhost on my ubuntu 17.04, localhost address is `http://localhost/js/angular/4/` and the program is not working in Google Chrome, the same code runs all fine on Firefox, and if I rename the same folder to another number or if I keep the same code in another folder, it seems to be working all fine. What could be the reason of this weird behavior as I couldn't find anything similar to this on Internet while searching for the solution.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello World";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{ message}}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you get in console/screen/logs?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-app` and `ng-controller` can't be on the same element.

Comment: sorry, corrected it in the question, it is indeed on different elements in actual code. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The example is working fine above when selecting `Run code snippet` if it isn't running for you on your local, make sure all your files are loaded and you don't have any weird console errors. Short of that everything looks good.

Comment: thanks for replying again, but that is the case, the code is running on codepen, firefox and even on chrome if I am running the file directly, but it isn't running using localhost, and isn't giving any errors as well.

Comment: Are all the correct versions of your files being loaded?

Comment: Yes sir, they were all correctly loading, **It seems to be working all fine after restarting apache**. Thank you for helping along. :)